# CSS Layout Questions (Table like layout with dynamically sized cells)

Tags: html, css

Hy there,

I need to build a layout that looks something like this:
[image: Layout]

The requirements are the following:

- Every row has 3 cells
- The width of left & right cells is not known and adjusts to their content
- The middle cell should always take the remaining space and should adjust it's height according to it's content automatically
- The left cell should always have the same height as it's containing div (row) which is again given by the height of the middle cell (100 % height)

I've already managed to accomplish the first 3 points with this setting:

- Left div: float left
- Right div: float right
- Center div: overflow: hidden
- Important: The right div has to be declared BEFORE the center div in the markup to work

The problem is that i can't think of any way to make the left cell always the same height as the row respectively the center cell. 100 % height doesn't work because of it's floating state...

Example code and [working testcase](http://jsfiddle.net/HV2vh/7/):

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="inner left">xxxxxxx</div>
        <div class="inner right">yyyyyyy</div>
        <div class="inner middle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="inner left">xxx</div>
        <div class="inner right">yyyyyyyyyyy</div>
        <div class="inner middle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="inner left">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
        <div class="inner right">yyy</div>
        <div class="inner middle">Lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    width: 500px;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner {
    min-height: 24px;
}

.inner.left {
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
}

.inner.middle {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner.right {
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
}
```

I'd really appreciate any help with this!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `display:table` to have something close.
http://jsfiddle.net/HV2vh/8/

```
.outer {
    width: 500px;
    margin:1em auto;
}
.row {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:table;
}
.inner {
    min-height: 24px;
    display:table-cell;
    width:1%;
}
.inner.left {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.inner.middle {
    background-color: red;
    width:7.5%;
}
.inner.right {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Using display: table & table-cell did the trick for me!
Thanks